# gradle многомодульный проект - не видит классы из зависимого модуля

Tags: java, gradle, jar, модули, зависимости

В корне проекта
settings.gradle:

```
rootProject.name = 'Gradle_Multiproject'

include 'main_project', 'library_project'
```

В папке /main_project файл build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "application"

mainClassName = "com.example.Main"

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile project(":library_project")
}

jar {
    manifest.attributes("Main-Class": mainClassName);
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = "1.12"
}
```

Main.java

```
package com.example;

import com.example.Simple;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("main project");

        Simple simple = new Simple();
    }
}
```

В папке /library_project файл build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: "java"

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
```

Simple.java:

```
package com.example;

public class Simple {
    private int value;

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Если сбилдить из корня `gradle build`, а затем из-под main_project запустить

```
java -jar build/libs/main_project.jar
```

то выйдет ошибка что класс Simple не найден.

Как тогда подключить классы из зависимого модуля, указанного в depencencies как compile project?

Answer (score 1):

**По дефолту таск jar не пакует зависимости в вашу jar**. Вам нужно либо указать в classpath путь до library_project.jar, либо спаковать зависимости (это называется **fat-jar**) в main_project.jar. Это можно сделать так:

```
jar {
manifest.attributes("Main-Class": mainClassName);

from {
    configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
}
}
```

http://www.baeldung.com/gradle-fat-jar

Comment: А для чего тогда я указываю compile project, если все-равно желаемого результата без специального таска это не даёт. Только что при компиляции не ругается на неизвестный класс из зависимости?